# Blazor UPnP setup

Tags: c#, websocket, blazor, httpclient, upnp

I'd like to programmatically set up port forwarding from within a browser-based Blazor client (net60) so it can receive requests from the Internet.  Legacy solutions use the Socket to achieve this, but in Blazor, there's no Socket available.  Anybody already gone through this?

Comment: Blazor (webassembly) is subject to all JavaScript security restrictions. This is not going to work. Blazor serverside  might be an option.

Comment: I expected as much.  There will not be a server option unfortunately.  Just hoping for someone's clever sideload idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a hybrid solution where the user uses a port forwarding application to punch the router holes needed by the blazor app.